# ASP.NET Core mangling string variable used for style

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to do something I thought would be simple, but has turned out to be incredibly frustrating. All I want to do is check if a certain field is set, and if it is insert inline css into an element.

```
@{
    string headerStyle = string.Empty;

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(appOptions.Color))
    {
        headerStyle = $"style=\"background-color: {appOptions.Color};\"";
    }
}

<nav class="navbar" @headerStyle>
  ...
</nav>
```

So if `Color` has no value, do nothing. If it does, insert the inline css. Inspecting the View as it's loaded, `headerStyle` has the correct value after being checked:

```
style="background-color: lightyellow;"
```

Perfect. Just insert that into the opening tag of the element. But no, when the View renders in the browser it looks like this:

```
<nav class="navbar" style=""background-color:" lightyellow;&quot;>
```

So it appears to insert an additional quote after `style=` on its own, as well as one after `background-color:` Then it encodes the trailing quote at the end of the tag. Is there a way to just have this string be inserted verbatim without all of this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the string with `Html.Raw()` did it.

`<nav class="navbar" @Html.Raw(headerStyle)>`